# TypeError: $(...).fullscreen is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a full-screen button for opening page elements in fullscreen mode. So I use this plugin https://github.com/private-face/jquery.fullscreen/
It's working fine on there `examples/index.html` but when I use this on my theme it doesn't working and it's showing `TypeError: $(...).fullscreen is not a function` inside console .

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>(successfully loaded)
<script src="{$smarty.const.CURR_THEME}jquery.fullscreen.min.js"></script>(successfully loaded)
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // open in fullscreen
        $('#fullscreen .requestfullscreen').click(function() {
            $('#fullscreen').fullscreen();
            return false;
        });

        // exit fullscreen
        $('#fullscreen .exitfullscreen').click(function() {
            $.fullscreen.exit();
            return false;
        });

        // document's event
        $(document).bind('fscreenchange', function(e, state, elem) {
        // if we currently in fullscreen mode
            if ($.fullscreen.isFullScreen()) {
                $('#fullscreen .requestfullscreen').hide();
                $('#fullscreen .exitfullscreen').show();
            } else {
                $('#fullscreen .requestfullscreen').show();
                $('#fullscreen .exitfullscreen').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<li id="fullscreen" class="dropdown codo_dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="requestfullscreen btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></span> Fullscreen</button>
    <button type="button" class="exitfullscreen btn btn-default btn-sm" style="display: none"></button>
</li>
```

I can't fix this please help me! Sorry for my bad English.

Thank you !

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: when I use `jQuery(function($) {` it doesn't get error but when I click on this button it's showing a white blank page .

Comment: can it be the fullscreen only works on <div>, not on <li> ?

Comment: I create it for body it's working now but won't scroll